# Summation of fractions with odd denominators to prove by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> $$
> \frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} =
> \frac{n}{2n+1}
> $$

As you can imagine I am stuck in third step in $k+1$. Hope you can help.

Comment: Can you please share your first and second steps, and explain where exactly you're "stuck in the third step"? BTW, you could have given a better title than that repetitive statement up there.

Comment: First step: n=1 we have 1/1 ×3=1/2 *1+1. And this is true because we have 1/3 =1/3

Comment: You're generally expected to show a little more effort (that is, if you're expecting others to make the same effort for you).

Comment: Second step: we take it true for n=k. So we have 1/1*3+1/3*5+...1/(2k-1)*(2k+1) =k/2k+1. And then it comes the third step to prove it for k+1

Comment: And thanks for advice. I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\dfrac{1}{2+1}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\dfrac{n}{2n+1}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}}+\dfrac{1}{(2(n+1)-1)(2(n+1)+1)}=$

$\color\red{\dfrac{n}{2n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{(2(n+1)-1)(2(n+1)+1)}=$

$\dfrac{n+1}{2(n+1)+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: I know that this is the way how I can solve it but the problem is that I don't know how to proceed in the last step.

Comment: @Alsina: That last steps shows $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\dfrac{n+1}{2(n+1)+1}$. Where do you want to proceed???

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining good what I mean. I stuck here k/(2k+1) + 1 /(2k+1)*(2k +3)= k+1/2(k+1) +1. I need to prove that this is true. How can I prove it?

Comment: @Alsina: You can't, it's not true (well, it's true only for $k=-1$ and for $k=\frac12$, I'm pretty sure that not what you're trying to prove).

Comment: Actually I just get this math induction lessons and I don't understand it good. I just try to follow the tree steps that I learned. Hmmm there something wrong with this exercise

Comment: @Alsina: Perhaps you want to try and read my answer again, one line at a time, and see if you understand it?

Comment: In the third step where have you proved that this is true for k+1?

Comment: @Alsina:Read carefully. It says "prove that this is true for $n+1$". I'm using $k$ only as a "temporary variable" in the $\sum$.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I will try better to understand this. I know there is a solution waiting for me to understand it.